# disable / enable apple remote in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, infrared

I want to disable or enable apple remote with a cmd running in terminal.

I am able to set the value `DeviceEnabled` in `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleIRController.plist` successfully:

`defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleIRController.plist DeviceEnabled -bool YES` or `NO`.

If i check `system preferences > security > general > advanced > disable remote control infrared receiver`the correct value is shown.

But the remote disabled/enabled status hasn't changed.

So i think i have to kill or restart some process. Which one?
Or any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: This works after reboot.

Comment: That's not an option :) but thanks. I want to switch remote option immediately

Comment: This post is kinda technical but it explains why just setting the preference does't work: https://robert.sesek.com/2016/3/bezelservices_on_os_x.html. You also need to tell the IR remote driver that the value changed. He links to some code that can do this in terminal.

Comment: thanks, kinda technical :)